# What to do when word ends in は

Tags: sentence, morae

This question probably sounds stupid, but I may as well ask.
Let’s say I have a dog named Donnaha (pronounced as “dough-nah-hah”), I write it as どんなは.

If I say something like どんなはは犬です, is this grammatically correct? Can I use は after は?

It’s a very specific case, I know, but I figured it might be nice to know. If some words end with HA or WA, I’d like to know how to handle them.

Comment: はははははははははははと笑った。

Comment: How about いろはは昔の順ですよね。Or ははははの秋の色がだいすきです。

Comment: I wonder what made you think は might be different from other particles such as が and に.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much you can do or need to do.

どんなはは犬です is grammatical, but it would give a difficulty in parsing especially because  どんな is an existing word. For the particular case, it is better to write ドンナハは犬です. (BTW Donnaha is really a possible dog name?)

Similarly use of Kanji and punctuations would make sentences more readable. The sentence given in the comment is an instance of classic quiz. Slightly different versions:

- はははははじょうぶだ。
- ははのははははははははははははははとわらう。

See [here](http://radphys4.c.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Etorii/home/etc/hahaha.html) for the answers (click the link). Also note that, being written only in hiragana aside, they are a bit artificial.